# Postgres update multiple deep jsonb elements in single query

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

### Context

Imagine a table in Postgres with a `jsonb` field, having `depth > 1`

```json
{
    "k1":
    {
        "k1.1": "v1.1",
        "k1.2": "v1.2"
    },
    "k2":
    {
        "k2.1": "v2.1",
        "k2.2": "v2.2",
        "k2.3": "v2.3"
    }
}
```

### Question

Is there a way to modify this field using `jsonb` functions so that multiple json elements are updated in a single query?

In the example above, the output would be:

```json
{
    "k1":
    {
        "k1.1": "v1.1-updated",
        "k1.2": "v1.2"
    },
    "k2":
    {
        "k2.1": "v2.1",
        "k2.2": "v2.2",
        "k2.3": "v2.3-updated"
    }
}
```

### Nice-to-haves

- should work for arbitrary complexity of json structures
- should scale nicely (i.e. without impacting the query performance + readability too much) when adding additional json field modifications

### Suboptimal solutions

**1. Achieves the objective, but syntax doesn't scale nicely**

```
jsonb_set(
  jsonb_set(value, '{k1,k1.1}', '"v1.1-updated"'::jsonb), 
  '{k2,k2.3}', '"v2.3-updated"'::jsonb)
```

Adding further modifications would require recursively nesting additional `jsonb_set` functions within each other, impacting readability and making the query harder to maintain.

**2. Doesn't achieve the objective, but is a good example of a syntax that would scale nicely**

The following query would drop the fields instead of modifying them

```
value
  #- '{k1,k1.1}'
  #- '{k2,k2.3}'
```

Dropping additional fields would only add 1 line for each field dropped.

Comment: Please do share what you have achieved so far, so people here can answer this better.

Comment: How do you define those "modifications"? Your single example is not enough for us to generalise. Could be a simple `jsonb_set(jsonb_set(value, '{k1,k1.1}', '"v1.1-updated"'::jsonb), '{k2,k2.3}', '"v2.3-updated"'::jsonb)`

Comment: Why do you need it to "scale"? How many modifications do you want to do? Are they somehow dynamic?

Comment: You can assume a JSON field of ~100 elements, with ~20 of them being modified like this. An example of a modification might be masking some JSON elements considered sensitive data.

Comment: And you need to write this as SQL code, it's not somehow passed as a parameter value? And you can't generate the SQL either?

Comment: Correct -- the idea is to have a view that contains all the json contents, except the "dropped" ones